# The id value must be unique in dreamweaver?

Tags: javascript, html, css, adobe, dreamweaver

Why its showing like for few id. [image]

What i am making wrong on this

```
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
          <button id="startHour" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">hour</button>

            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="startHour">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">1</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">3</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">4</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">5</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">6</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">7</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">8</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">9</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">10</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">11</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">12</a>
            </div>
            <span style="color:white; background-color:#5A6268">:</span>
 <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
          <button id="startMinute" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" 
  data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">min</button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="startMinute">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">00</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">05</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">10</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">15</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">20</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">25</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">30</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">35</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">40</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">45</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">50</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">55</a>
          </div>
 </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">am</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">zone</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Set</button>

      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">hour</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">min</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">am</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">zone</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Set</button>
    </div>

    </td>

  </tr>
```

Here i am using same for drop down list. startHour and startMinute are the unique id which, I am using for drop down the hour and minute and also, it used for more than 20 times. For few drop down it shows id must be unique. what does it mean..

Comment: It means that somewhere else in your code, you have an element with `startHour` id. Search through your code. Maybe it's copy-pasted elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

In html every tag need to be unique. If you need same id for 2 element, time to for thinking class.
For more info  [click here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

in javascript  the dom's id just like a public variable；
example   this domObject is in window.a;
so the id must be unique;